# Windscribe CLI issue

Tags: 16.04, vpn

I have recently installed windscribe cli for linux, exactly the same way as they have mentioned on their official page. Link to the official page is [this](https://windscribe.com/guides/linux).

After successful install, I logged in using `windscribe login`. Then I would like to connect to United Kingdom, so I issued this `windscribe connect GB`. It says successfully connected to United Kingdom. More precisely this;

```
Connecting to United Kingdom (UDP:443)
Firewall Enabled
Connected to United Kingdom
Your IP changed from xxx.xxx.x.xxx to yy.yyy.yy.yy
```

But when I search `https://www.google.com/`, it connects me back to my country's Google and not to that of United Kingdom's. Is there anything that I am missing? I have windscribe on my Windows 7 PC as well and it just works fine, but not on Ubuntu. One thing I would like to mention is that, once, it did connect to UK (just after the install) but it is not connecting now. I used the same steps to connect on the maiden run after the install and I am still using those steps only. But, alas, nothing working now.

Please help!!

Comment: You should [edit] your question to say what windscribe is.

Comment: They say that windscribe for linux ist still in beta - but you must contact them in any case - we **cannot** support it.

Comment: Well thanks!! Although my issue is not solved but I found a way around the problem. I added windscribe chrome extension and now I can use the VPN.